# Pytorch/Numpy: Subtract each of N elements from a single matrix, resulting in N matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Question in the title. Is there an operation or way to broadcast to do this without looping? Here's a simple example with list comprehension:

```
image = torch.tensor([[6, 9], [8.7, 5.5]])
c = torch.tensor([5.7675, 8.8325])

# with list comprehension
desired_result = torch.stack([image - c_i for c_i in c])

# output:
tensor([[[ 0.2325,  3.2325],
         [ 2.9325, -0.2675]],

        [[-2.8325,  0.1675],
         [-0.1325, -3.3325]]])
```

I've tried reshaping the "scalar array" every which way to get the desired results with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if `torch` has `outer`:

```
- np.subtract.outer(c.numpy(), image.numpy() )
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0.23250008,  3.2325    ],
        [ 2.9325    , -0.26749992]],

       [[-2.8325005 ,  0.16749954],
        [-0.13250065, -3.3325005 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

In torch, you can flatten the two tensors and reshape:

```
-(c[:,None] - image.ravel()).reshape(*c.shape, *image.shape)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[ 0.2325,  3.2325],
         [ 2.9325, -0.2675]],

        [[-2.8325,  0.1675],
         [-0.1325, -3.3325]]])
```

Comment: Yes [`torch.outer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.outer.html?highlight=outer#torch.outer) does exist but not for multi-dimensional inputs ;(

Comment: @rocksNwaves do you need to perform back propagation on it?

Comment: @Ivan yes, its for the loss function in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02872.pdf